# Hrefs not clickable on Iphone

Tags: iphone, html, anchor

I'm trying to make [www.theothereye.tv](http://www.theothereye.tv) accessible on the iPhone, but for some reason the `<a>` tags aren't clickable.

I've looked around on Google, and everything points to people’s iOS being broken.

Nothing appearing on SO either.

Any ideas?

/*Edit*/

Here is the code surrounded by a div that is causing issues

```
<div id="itemsContainer"> 
    <a href="index.html" onClick="home_click(); GATrackEvent('menu_bar', 'Home',''); return false;"><img id="logo" src="Img/Logo.png"></a> 
    <a id="contact_A" href="#" onClick="scrollContact();  GATrackEvent('menu_bar', 'Contact',''); return false;"><img id="contact" src="Img/Contact.png"></a><br/> 
    <a id="reel_A" href="reel.html" onClick="reel_click(); GATrackEvent('menu_bar', 'Reel',''); return false;"><img id="reel" src="Img/Reel.png"></a><br/> 
    <a id="info_A" href="#" onClick="scrollInfo(); GATrackEvent('menu_bar', 'Info',''); return false;"><img id="info" src="Img/Info.png"></a><br/> 
</div> 

    /*CSS*/
#itemsContainer
{
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    z-index:99;
    width:100%;
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure link tags aren't broken on iOS. I suspect I'd have noticed.

Comment: Can you post come code that you are using? Make sure you add `http://` because even HTML pages won't properly work if you just have `www.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you enabled the developer option on your iPhone's Safari Settings to see if JavaScript errors are raised when you click those links?

Comment: I wouldn't know where to start on that... I'll look!

Comment: For the record: Home screen > Settings > Safari > Developer > Debug Console: On. See http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/2SafariDeveloperTools/SafariDeveloperTools.html

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code you’ve now posted, all of those links include an `onclick` attribute that returns false. So, the expected behaviour when clicking or tapping those links is for the JavaScript in the `onclick` attribute to run, and the link not to be followed.

Have you checked in the Mobile Safari debug console for JavaScript errors? Could you put an `alert` at the top of `reel_click()` to confirm that it’s being run when the link is tapped on?

Comment: No, everything works fine on the desktop - across all browsers - even works ok an android. There is one link with a HREF - this was to account for non-JS users.

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar: right. Could you post the code for that link in your question so that we don’t have to hunt through your source code for it?

Comment: Paul D. Wait - I like you're bluntness :)

Comment: @Stuart.Sklinar: aw, thank you! I’m much wimpier in real life.